# WP only display categories that contain posts from that post type

Tags: php, wordpress

In wordpress I've created 2 custom post types `Services` & `Work` which can use the wp default category and tag taxonomies.

On any given single post page I need to list the categories available for that post type.

I've tried using
 `$args = array( 'hide_empty' => 1, 'taxonomy' => 'category' ); wp_list_categories( $args );` 
to list only those categories with posts associated but the list doesnt take the post types into account.

How would I only list the categories being used by that post type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question answered [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96444/only-list-categories-that-contain-posts-of-a-specific-custom-post-type):

> Put the following in your `functions.php`:
>
> ```
> function wp_list_categories_for_post_type($post_type, $args = '') {
>     $exclude = array();
>
>     // Check ALL categories for posts of given post type
>     foreach (get_categories() as $category) {
>         $posts = get_posts(array('post_type' => $post_type, 'category' => $category->cat_ID));
>
>         // If no posts found, ...
>         if (empty($posts))
>             // ...add category to exclude list
>             $exclude[] = $category->cat_ID;
>     }
>
>     // Set up args
>     if (! empty($exclude)) {
>         $args .= ('' === $args) ? '' : '&';
>         $args .= 'exclude='.implode(',', $exclude);
>     }
>
>     // List categories
>     wp_list_categories($args);
> }
> ```
>
> Now you can call `wp_list_categories_for_post_type('photos');` or
>   `wp_list_categories_for_post_type('videos',
>   'order=DESC&title_li=Cats');` and the like.